# What does the cs register do here?

Tags: disassembly, x86

I've come across this sequence of bytes: `2e 88 38`.

[Hopper](https://www.hopperapp.com/) disassembles this as:

```
mov    byte [cs:rax], bh
```

[This online disassembler](https://defuse.ca/online-x86-assembler.htm#disassembly) gives slightly different output:

```
mov    BYTE PTR cs:[rax],bh
```

Either way, I can't make heads nor tails of what the intended result of this instruction is.

Comment: I think it's the same meaning with slightly different syntax.

Comment: @macro_controller That was my assumption, but given I couldn't tell what either meant I didn't want to jump to that conclusion and leave something potentially important out of the question

Comment: It might not even be a valid instruction -- that is to say, does it make sense in the context of the surrounding instructions, or are they nonsensical?

Answer (score 2):

In 16- and 32-bit modes the  memory accesses used the ds or ss registers, but by using *segment override*, you could force usage of another segment (selector in protected mode). For example, in 16-bit real mode

```
 mov bx, [si]
```

Would access the address ds*16 + si

While

```
 mov bx, cs:[si]
```

Would access cs*16+si

The distinction was less useful in most 32-but OSes, which usually set up memory so that cs, ds, es, ss all pointed to the same flat 32-bit memory space although in theory they could be different (and often they did have different permissions). In 64-bit mode the segment registers are even less useful - in it the segment overrides are officially ignored except for fs and gs.

So in your example the cs prefix (2e) is completely redundant and serves no useful purpose: the instruction has the same effect as

```
mov  byte [rax], bh
```

However the disassembler still prints `cs:` to show that the prefix is  present in the instruction.

Answer (score 0):

char * rax; = bh
or byte* rax = bh or
simply mov the **[8..16]** bit component  of rbx register into the address pointed by 64 bit register rax  at **[0..7]** bit place and zero out the remaining bits

or in other words if address **12345678`9abcdef** contains **0x0**

and register rbx contains **0x00000000`0000ffff**

then after this operation address  **12345678`9abcdef**  will contain **0xff**

see below a simulation of operation with windbg

```
0:000> ? @rip
Evaluate expression: 140705686294668 = 00007ff8`9873108c
0:000> dq @rip l1
00007ff8`9873108c  c338c483`4800ebcc
0:000> r @rax = @rip
0:000> r @rbx = 0xffff
0:000> r @bh
bh=ff
0:000> eq @rax
00007ff8`9873108c c338c483`4800ebcc @bh
00007ff8`98731094 cccccccc`cccccccc
0:000> dq @rip l1
00007ff8`9873108c  00000000`000000ff
0:000>
```

and cs, ds, es , ss segment registers do not matter much in flat memory model.

only fs and gs segment registers matters

a sample code that demonstrates the write using various segment prefixes in x64
ml64 wont encode the instruction so need to emit raw bytes using define byte

c code with inline assembly usage follows

cpp file

```
:\>type inline_cpp.cpp

#include <windows.h>
extern "C" void segregtest(ULONG64 *addr ,BYTE value);
ULONG64 myaddr = 0x77;
int main (void)
{
        segregtest(&myaddr,0x88);
        return 0;
}
```

asmfile

```
:\>type inline_asm.asm
PUBLIC segregtest
.code
segregtest PROC
mov rax,rcx
mov bh,dl
db 2Eh
mov byte ptr [rax] ,    bh
add bh,11h
db 3Eh
mov byte ptr [rax] ,    bh
add bh,11h
db 36h
mov byte ptr [rax] ,    bh
add bh,11h
db 26h
mov byte ptr [rax] ,    bh
add bh,11h
db 64h
mov byte ptr [rax] ,    bh
add bh,11h
db 65h
mov byte ptr [rax] ,    bh
ret
segregtest ENDP
END
```

compile link with

```
:\>type assemble_compile_link.bat
ml64 /c /Zi /nologo %1_asm.asm

cl /Zi /W4 /Od /analyze /nologo /GS- /EHsc %1_cpp.cpp /link /release /subsystem:windows /fixed /entry:main %1_asm.obj
```

execution and tracing

```
:\>assemble_compile_link.bat inline

:\>cdb -c "g inline_cpp!segregtest;t 10;q" inline_cpp.exe | awk /Reading/,/quit/
0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'g inline_cpp!segregtest;t 10;q'
inline_cpp!segregtest+0x3:
00000001`40001003 8afa            mov     bh,dl
inline_cpp!segregtest+0x5:
00000001`40001005 2e8838          mov     byte ptr cs:[rax],bh cs:00000001`40003000=77
inline_cpp!segregtest+0x8:
00000001`40001008 80c711          add     bh,11h
inline_cpp!segregtest+0xb:
00000001`4000100b 3e8838          mov     byte ptr ds:[rax],bh ds:00000001`40003000=88
inline_cpp!segregtest+0xe:
00000001`4000100e 80c711          add     bh,11h
inline_cpp!segregtest+0x11:
00000001`40001011 368838          mov     byte ptr ss:[rax],bh ss:00000001`40003000=99
inline_cpp!segregtest+0x14:
00000001`40001014 80c711          add     bh,11h
inline_cpp!segregtest+0x17:
00000001`40001017 268838          mov     byte ptr es:[rax],bh es:00000001`40003000=aa
inline_cpp!segregtest+0x1a:
00000001`4000101a 80c711          add     bh,11h
inline_cpp!segregtest+0x1d:
00000001`4000101d 648838          mov     byte ptr fs:[rax],bh fs:00000001`40003000=bb
inline_cpp!segregtest+0x20:
00000001`40001020 80c711          add     bh,11h
inline_cpp!segregtest+0x23:
00000001`40001023 658838          mov     byte ptr gs:[rax],bh gs:00000001`40003000=cc
(1b44.cf8): Access violation - code c0000005 (first chance)
First chance exceptions are reported before any exception handling.
This exception may be expected and handled.
quit:
```

Comment: "*and cs ds es segemtn registers do not matter much in flat memory model*" - This is the part my question was about - I understand the `mov` instruction works usually, what I can't figure out (or search for apparently) is what `[cs:rax]` (or `cs:[rax]`) means

Comment: added a snippet that shows usage